# NSPredicate for obtaining all Students with a certain Course name?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nspredicate

I have two Entities, Student and Course, where each has a to-many relationship to the other (i.e., a Student has 0 or more Courses, and a Course has 0 or more Students).

I need to obtain all Students who are enrolled in a Course.  I also need to obtain all Courses in which a given Student is enrolled (by firstName).

An pseudo-predicate would be: *all students who have a course whose name is equal to courseName*.

So my question consists of two parts:

1. What is a valid NSPredicate for obtaining all students with a certain course name?
2. What is a valid NSPredicate for obtaining all courses where a student with a certain firstName is enrolled.

For your reference, here are my entities:

[image]

Comment: There will be a `NSSet` property in your `NSManagedObject` subclass, which returns students for a course object and courses for a student object.

Comment: if you are satisfied with any of the answers, please mark them correct. :)

Comment: @santhu will do.  need to try them out first.  thanks!

Answer (score 1):

1) Use this to filter an array of `students` that are in a specific course with `courseName` :

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY courses.name like %@", courseName]
```

Alternatively, if you already have a `course` object (and `name` is unique in call `course` objects), you can simply get all of its students by accessing its `students` property, i.e.

```
course.students // returns an NSSet/NSOrderedSet based on your model setup
```

2) Use this to filter an array of `courses` that have a student with a certain `firstName` :

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY students.firstName like %@", firstName]
```

Note: `NSSet` and `NSOrderedSet` have a method `array` to get an array of the objects.

See also the docs on [NSPredicate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pUsing.html) under *Using Predicates with Key-Paths*.

Answer (score 1):

What is a valid NSPredicate for obtaining all students with a certain course name?

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name= %@", courseName];
```

Use above predicate to fetch particular course while has name = courseName;Set that predicate on "Course" entity not "Student" entity.
AFter executing above fetch request, you will have array of courses having that courseName.

```
Course *course = [fetchedResults objectAtIndex:0];
```

Now to get all students in that course,

```
NSArray *students =[course.students allObjects];
```

now students is an array of "Student" entity objects.

Similarly ,
What is a valid NSPredicate for obtaining all courses where a student with a certain firstName is enrolled.

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"firstName = %@", name];
```

Use above predicate to fetch particular student who has name = firstName;Set that predicate on "Student" entity.
AFter executing above fetch request, you will have array of students having that firstName.

```
Student *student = [fetchedResults objectAtIndex:0];
```

Now to get all courses for that student,

```
NSArray *courses =[student.courses allObjects];
```

now courses is an array of "Course" entity objects.

Hope this helps.